# Script or Batch File to Automate Logon from Welcome Screen

Tags: windows-xp, login, script

Is there a script or batch file to automate the log-on process from the XP Welcome screen? As all details are the same Username, Password, and Domain in a room of 30 machines.

The reason I don't use Windows AutoAdminLogon is I only want to logon temporary at different times as a user to run such things as online test for a class of high school students without the students logging on individually first, also it would be useful for admin tasks if I can change/specify the user details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Microsoft's solution for doing it. It involves a Registry change on each computer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231

Answer (score 0):

[Sysinternals Autologon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx)

> Autologon enables you to easily configure Windows’ built-in autologon mechanism. Instead of waiting for a user to enter their name and password, Windows uses the credentials you enter with Autologon, which are encrypted in the Registry, to log on the specified user automatically.
>
> Autologon is easy enough to use. Just run autolog.exe, fill in the dialog, and hit Enable. To turn off auto-logon, hit Disable. If the DefaultPassword is NULL, autologon will only occur once and then be disabled. Also, if the shift key is held down before the system performs an autologon, the autologon will be disabled for that logon. You can also pass the username, domain and password as command-line arguments: autologon user domain password